# dynamic smtp not working with queueble mail in laravel

Tags: laravel, email, queue

trying to implement dynamic SMTP with laravel it works fine without queue mail but when adding queue to mail it takes default mail SMTP details

```
dispatch(function () use ($details, $email, $name, $tutorEmail, $brandName, $ownerEmail, $createdBy, $mailSubject) {
                Mail::send('mail.mailSchedule', $details, function ($m) use ($email, $name, $tutorEmail, $brandName, $ownerEmail, $createdBy, $mailSubject) {
                    $m->to($email, $name);
                    $m->from($ownerEmail, $brandName);
                    $m->subject($mailSubject);
                });
            })->delay(now()->addSeconds());
```

Comment: please add code or details about your "dynamic" SMTP solution.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic configuration in mail is not compatible with queue jobs because the configuration settings, such as the server address and port, may change while the job is in the queue. When the job is pulled from the queue and executed, the configuration settings may no longer be valid, resulting in the job failing to send the email.
The solution of this problem is to pass the email configuration settings as an argument when the job is pushed to the queue, so that the job has access to the correct settings at the time of execution.